# Is there a way to catch user is not authenticated exception?

Tags: python, django

I am calling a stored procedure via AJAX request, which requires user id.

If the user is not logged in i need to raise an exception. How is this possible? Note that I am using `@login_required` decorator which I have to remove in order for the function to work.

```
@require_POST
def mail_forward_action(request):
   try:
    ...cal procedure
   except UserIsNotAuthenticated
```

Comment: If you are using the `login_required` decorator, doesn't that mean no unauthenticated user will ever even reach `mail_forward_action` function?

Comment: Yes it does. I have to remove that

Comment: `request.user.is_authenticated`?

Comment: do i have to use an if statement at the top of each view?

Comment: What's wrong with using `login_required`? It is essentially what you want to do?

Comment: the view is requested via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if use is authenticated or not like this:

```
request.user.is_authenticated # This returns either True or False
```

So rather than raising exception you can create a function and make sure the user passes that test.

```
def logged_in(user_instance):
    return user_instance.is_authenticated

@user_passes_test(logged_in)
@require_POST
def mail_forward_action(request):
    ...cal procedure
```

Comment: How can i send an httpresponse when a user is not logged in? Like a message info

Comment: I think you'll have to use wrappers to achieve that. This documentation might help: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps